# Why is REPO concatenating remote address and folder?

Tags: git, version-control, repo

I'm trying to use repo to fetch several git repositories for a project. I have a personal git server where all the git repositories are hosted

I'm able to manually clone individual repos executing this command:

```
git clone my_repo@my_repo_address:repo_a
```

But since I need the same repositories for different projects I decided to use REPO instead of cloning manually.

I have created a **default.xml** file to work with and it contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote  name="project"
           fetch="my_repo@my_repo_address"/>

  <project name="repo_a" remote="project" revision="master" path="a"/>
  <project name="repo_b" remote="project" revision="master" path="b"/>
  <project name="repo_c" remote="project" revision="master" path="c"/>
</manifest>
```

I have this default.xml file hosted on the same git server on a repository called **git-repo-fetch**. I can successfully init the repo as follows:

```
 repo init -u my_repo@my_repo_address:git-repo-fetch
```

And it inits successfully. But when I execute **repo sync** I get the error:

```
Fetching project repo_c
fatal: 'git-repo-fetch/my_repo@my_repo_address/repo_c' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

And my question is **why is repo concatenating the XML repo name (git-repo-fetch) with the fetch address (my_repo@my_repo_address)?**

By doing so, it tries to fetch from **git-repo-fetch/my_repo@my_repo_address** which is wrong.

Comment: Why isn't the url `my_repo@my_repo_address/git-repo-fetch` or ``my_repo@my_repo_address:port_number/git-repo-fetch``? The ":" makes the following `git-repo-fetch` look like a port number.

Comment: In https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols I find that the ssh url can be `git clone ssh://user@server/project.git` or `git clone user@server:project.git`. Try the former format. Maybe REPO doesn't support the latter.

Comment: @ElpieKay if I do `ssh://user@server/project.git` I get the message `fatal: '/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository`. The only way I can clone is if I use `git clone user@server:project.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see (like in [this thread from 2011](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/repo-discuss/ssh$20scp%7Csort:relevance/repo-discuss/VTqvzbQCszo/7AYd7OFwbcIJ)), **[`repo`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-repo/)** has always supported the ssh:// URL scheme

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

And *not* the scp-like syntax `user@host:repo`.

> `user@host:path` is a nice shorthand on the command line, but **`ssh://` is less ambiguous for a manifest XML file**.

With the scp-syntax, `repo` does "munge" the URL, as [mentioned in 2012](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/kCXO-NdFvj4/xOhR7MbgKooJ).

Comment: Yeah, this solved the issue. I had to add the whole `/path/to/repo/` to my `default.xml` file.