# repo removes organization name from URL

Tags: git, github, repo

We are using repo to download several projects from github. As expected, the projects we want to download are declared in a manifest.xml file. Thus, to install repo and specify the URL from which to retrieve a manifest repository we use the following command:

`repo init -u git@github.com:organization_name/manifest.git`

After that, to download the sources and the respective changes we use:

`repo sync`

Nothing new so far with respect to workflow. However, since yesterday we detected that this workflow is not working for some reason that we do no understand.

Somehow, repo removes the `organization_name` from the URL and consequently it cannot find the repositories which belong to the organization. Here is an example of the error (it repeats for each of the github projects declared in the manifest):

```
project_1:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
project_1: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
error: Cannot fetch project_1 from ssh://git@github.com/project_1
```

Can someone pinpoint what maybe the causes for this issue?

**What have we tried so far?**

We tried using different repo versions, switching users and machines. In addition we also tried to switch from ssh access to https. All of the combinations yield the result reported above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46740757/7976758 Rumor has it google-repo doesn't (or at least didn't) support scp-like syntax. Try ssh syntax: `repo init -u ssh://git@github.com/organization_name/manifest.git`

Comment: @phd The link you provided helped figure out the issue. So for the record I modified the syntax in the`fetch` field of the remote in the manifest file to obey the ssh syntax rules. That solved the problem. Thank you for your help!