# Google repo: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, repo

I am experiencing a weird problem. I am using repo tool to clone all repos of a complex, multi-repo project. I am using Ubuntu 22, and 'repo' was installed via 'apt install'.

What I'm doing is:

```
repo init -b master -u git@bitbucket.org:my-user/my-project-manifesto.git
```

The manifest file has the following remote defined:

```
<remote name="bb" fetch="ssh://bitbucket.org/" />
```

And as far as I know this is correct format.

and then:

```
repo sync
```

Basically it fails for every bitbucket repo using the 'remote' defined above.The error is always "Permission denied (publickey)". My public key has been added to the bitbucket account, so this is not the problem. Also, I'm pretty sure it has worked in the past.

Interestingly, cloning any of the repos in manifesto works ok:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-user/my-repo1.git
```

So either 'repo' uses wrong key pair, there's a problem with the manifest file OR some kind of a problem on BB side.

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46740757/7976758 There is a rumor that `repo` supports `ssh://` URL syntax but not scp-like syntax `git@bitbucket.org:my-user/my-project-manifesto.git` . Change it to `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my-user/my-project-manifesto.git` and change URLs in manifest accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @phd. This is indeed the problem.